# android layout weight %

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to messing around with the Android layout weight attributes.
I want a vertical layout with "3 child layouts" The first will take 25% of the space, the second 50%, and the last 25% of the space. When I try to add to the last layout, everything just not working. What should be the weight for each of these layouts?

I get the weight attributes to work fine with just 2 layouts/elements and understand how it works but when I try with 3 I get a problem.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_weight="50" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="25" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout code so we can see what you've done

Comment: Yes.  The problem is your height attributes.  They should all be `0dp`.

Answer (score 5):

try using this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:weightSum="100">
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="25">
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="50" >
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_weight="25">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the `android:width` attribute is set to 0dp for all child layouts, and then make sure that you have a `weight` specified.  If you want a more detailed explanation, you will need to paste your code.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way of achieving this result using less complicated layout tree. You may use `PercentRelativeLayout` from [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#percent) for Android. Just import this library to your project, and check out the following code:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_widthPercent="25%">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_widthPercent="25%">
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, weight can only be applied to `LinearLayouts` or any layout that derives from `LinearLayout`. The weights of the children should be a percentage of whatever the `weightSum` attribute is for `LinearLayout`.  If you set `weightSum=1` of your parent `LinearLayout`, then the percentage of your first child should be .25, second child should be .5, and third child should be .25.

EDIT: Like javram said.  You need to set either the width or height to `0dp` depending on whether the `LinearLayout` is horizontal orientation or vertical orientation respectively.

EDIT 2: Also, I don't think you have to actually specify `weightSum`. It helps, but I believe `LinearLayout` will divide the children up base solely on how their own respective weights are. If child 1's weight is twice as large as child 2's weight, then child 2 will be double child 1 on screen.  Thus in your case just make sure child 1 & 3 have the same weight while child 2 has double the value the other two.

Answer (score -1):

```
LinearLayout java1,java2,java3;

    java1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.java1);
    java2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.java2);
    java3=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.java3);
    DisplayMetrics ds=new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(ds);
    int height=ds.heightPixels;
    Log.d(TAG,""+height);

    java1.getLayoutParams().height=height/4;
    java2.getLayoutParams().height=height/2;
    java3.getLayoutParams().height=height/4;
```