# Android Studio: Set button height/length to be some percentage of Android device?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to standardize the size of a button across multiple Android devices with regards to height and width.  For example, I'd like the length to be one-third of the device's width and the height to be about 5-10% of the device's height.  I've tried expanding upon:

```
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"

        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm running Android Studio 1.4.0.

-A

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44105138/7759828 , try using layout weight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout) in this case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.journaldev.percentlayouts.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="30%" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

I will require gradle dependancy as

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'
```

And if you are using latest API (**As [`PercentRelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout) is deprecated**) you can do it with `ConstraintLayout`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".15"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".85"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".15"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".85"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_guideline" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Being new to Android Studio, how do I get Percent Relative Layout into my app?  Do I create a new layout resource file?  If yes, how do I incorporate that into activity_main.xml?

Comment: @Aneyth Yes it will require gradle dependancy. Hope you found that. I have updated answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it programatically from java

1.get the device screen dimensions, and compute what you need.

2.call setHeight and setWidth on the target views, or through layout params.